# Ошибка при получении данных из контроллера ASP.NET Web API2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Всем привет использую ASP.NET Web Api с типом аутентификации Individual User Accounts при отправки данных клиенту полученных из БД, я на клиенте получаю код статуса 500 при этом исключений на сервере не наблюдалось. Есть что-то что блокирует?

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetCard(string data)
        {
            string[] data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(data);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(BadRequest(ModelState));
            }
            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                IEnumerable<WorkerCard> card = new CorpDb().WorkerCards.ToList();

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,card);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(Unauthorized());
        }
```

**Сторона сервера**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня такая ошибка бывала при неудачной инициализации контекста БД. Ошибка возникает только с этим контроллером, или всеми? Что за CorpDb?

Comment: Извините, а Вам не надо добавить await в строку чтения из базы, чтобы получилось IEnumerable<WorkerCard> card = await (new CorpDb().WorkerCards.ToList()); ? А то функция async, а это единственное место, где возможно ожидание

Comment: @bearpo со всеми контроллерами. Я могу вернуть любую другую инфу кроме которая лежит в БД ну и конечно можно вирнуть список пользователей он же ApplicationUser класс который идёт с шаблоном. CorpDb это второй контекст. У вас возникнет вопрос наверно может это из-за второго контекста но нет я пробовал и с одним контекстом такая же хрень. Поэтому перепробовав всё я прибегнул ко второму контексту. Такое впечатление что что-то перекрывает отправку данных клиенту. Пробовал создавать новый проект но сталкнулся с той же проблемой. Инициализация БД проходит гладко без всяких исключений.

Comment: @S.H нет не в этом проблема я пробовал по разному изначально использую все методы асинхронные. Это просто как для теста осталось не стал менять

Comment: Вообще, самый первый комментарий, похоже, самый правильный. Нельзя ли у этого CorpDb() вернуть - просто для теста - какое то свойство, которое есть только у правильно открытой базы? Может, к ней просто как то коннект не открывается?

Comment: @S.H. Но список пользователей можно же вернуть а значит соединение с базой имееться, ведь пользователи тоже хранятся в этой же базе. А что значит по вашему правильно открытая БД? если бы соединения не было то я бы не мог инициализировать БД. Забыл сказать я запрос делаю к базе данных и запрос удовлетворяет он тянет данные. Но когда я отправляю только что скачанные данные из БД, то на клиенте я получаю статус скодом 500.

Comment: А если поднастроить IIS чтобы кроме статуса получать также расшифровку ошибки? Вроде здесь описано, как это сделать: https://www.sql.ru/forum/520848/kak-zastavit-iis-otobrazhat-oshibki

Comment: @S.H. Я загрузил фото с верху чтоб вы увидели что данные тянутся и всё хорошо. Спасибо IIS это хорошо не знал что у него можно посмотреть ошибки все. а в каком конкретно месте можно увидеть, Это какой то журнал?

Comment: @ваняк Прямо на веб странице будет написано. Там, где сейчас error 500 - будет более подробная расшифровка ошибки, гуглить можно по "iis включить отображение ошибок" или "iis show error in browser"

Comment: Отлично, запрос сделал через **Postman** так как нжна авторизация и токен, проблему нашёл только не совсем понимаю в чём беда. Сереализовать в Json не может не понимаю вот стек трассировки исключений. 
`
{
    "Message": "Произошла ошибка.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property 'FK_User' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserProfile_6CD8CF4EEFE3715D833418A0838A9E5AD79B6AC96BC4D6F9B1880CCF8E21D09C'. Path '[0].FK_User.FK_ListOfWorkersRT[0]'.",
    "ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
    "StackTrace": "   
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена!
@S.H. Спасибо что направили куда посмотреть [Тут решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type/26255284#26255284). Проблема была в сереализации формата json либо в десереализации, на стороне сервера по этому и возваращало Status Code 500 у клиента.
Чтоб эту проблему решить есть два варианта для одного контекста и для множества контекстов. Опять же повторюсь я использовал  ASP.NET Web Api с типом аутентификации Individual User Accounts.

**Если у вас один контекст (DbContext)**

Затем в файле **Global.asax** в методе Application_Start() Добавляем строку

```
 JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
```

Будет выглядеть таким образом метод

```
protected async void Application_Start()
{
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
}
```

**Если же у вас несколько контекстов**
То в каждом контексте нужно внести две строчки

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

После этого должно выглядеть таким образом

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Detail> Details { get; set; } 
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

 public class ModelContext2: DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles{ get; set; } 

    public ModelContext2() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: В конечном итоге, ваша проблема же была не в самой ленивой загрузке, во взаимно-рекурсивных типах моделей. Я бы на вашем месте дополнил ответ.

Comment: @bearpro Спасибо, дополнил!